# path to xml via ClassPathXmlApplicationContext not working?

Tags: spring

XML path `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` not working,Please try to look at picture below and let me know what path I need to assign

package org.yashwanth.spring;

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class DrawingApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("yashwanth");
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        Triangle triangle=(Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");
        triangle.draw();

    }

}

package org.yashwanth.spring;

public class Triangle {
    private String type;
    public String getType() {
            return type;
        }
        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    public void draw(){
        System.out.println(getType()+"triangle drawn");
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

spring.xml( I am using here spring 4.2.1),I don't know whether bean definition is correct or wrong

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="triangle" class="org.yashwanth.spring.Triangle">
<property name="type" value="Equilateral"/>

</bean>


</beans>
```

Error message on console:

```
Dec 15, 2015 6:31:50 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1ed6993a: startup date [Tue Dec 15 06:31:50 EST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 15, 2015 6:31:50 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/yashwanth/spring/spring.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 1 in XML document from class path resource [org/yashwanth/spring/spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 39; Premature end of file.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:604)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:509)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.yashwanth.spring.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:11)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 39; Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: what error did u get?

Comment: put it in the root not in the package or change the path to `org/yashwanth/spring/spring.xml`.

Comment: I tried that one too Still I am getting error, Error:Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 1 in XML document from class path resource [org/yashwanth/spring/spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 39; Premature end of file.
 at

Comment: I think I had problem with Xml Bean defination as I am using spring 4.2.1 ,I am little concerned whether this s=is correct or not                                          <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  @M.Deinum

Comment: don't add code in comments, improve your answer and also add the error you get (the initial one and after changing).

Comment: I added the console error messgae and xml file, Can you go through it and  let me know why I am getting this error

Comment: It'S ok I got where I went wrong ,The definition itself is wrong in spring.xml,Thanks for help